# Express session reset for every request

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am trying to use session variables in express to manage user sign in. I can't get the variable to work over different requests. Here is my code:

```
var config = require('config'),

    ejs = require('ejs'),

    util = require('util'),

    express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    moment = require('moment'),
    plaid = require('plaid'),
    mariadb = require('mariadb'),

    fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    https = require('https'),

    session = require('express-session'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

...

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
    session({
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        secret: 'debug',
        cookie: { secure: true }
    })
);

...

app.post('/tokensignin', function (req, res) {
    async function verify() {
        const ticket = await googleAuthClient.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: req.body.idtoken,
            audience: GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
        });
        const payload = ticket.getPayload();
        const userid = payload['sub'];
        if (payload['aud'] == GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID) {
            pool.getConnection().then(conn => {
                conn.query("CALL getUserByGoogleId(?)", [userid])
                    .then(rows => {
                        res.sendStatus(200);
                        if (rows[0]) {
                            req.session.test = "Hello, world!";
                            console.log("req.session.test = " + req.session.test);
                            req.session.user = {
                                firstName: rows[0].firstName,
                                lastName: rows[0].lastName,
                                avatar: rows[0].imageUrl,
                            };
                        } else {
                            conn
                                .query("CALL createUser(?,?,?,?,?)) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
                                    , [userid, req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.imageUrl, req.body.email]
                                )
                                .then(rows => {
                                    req.session.user = {
                                        firstName: rows[0].firstName,
                                        lastName: rows[0].lastName,
                                        avatar: rows[0].imageUrl,
                                    };
                                })
                                .catch(err => {
                                    console.log("error: " + err);
                                    res.send(err);
                                });
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.send(err);
                    });
                conn.end();
            });
        }
    }
    verify().catch(console.error);
});
```

The variables are properly stored the first time, but when I redirect to the home page, `req.session.test` and `req.session.use` are undefined.

Here's the code for that:

```
app.all('/home', function (req, res) {
    console.log("req.session.test = " + req.session.test);
    console.log(req.session);
    return res.render('home.ejs', {
        PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY: PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY,
        PLAID_ENV: PLAID_ENV,
        PLAID_PRODUCTS: PLAID_PRODUCTS,
        APP_MODE: config.APP_MODE,
        APP_PORT: config.APP_PORT,
        URL: config.URL,
        test: req.session.test,
        user: req.session.user,
    });
});
```

I'm using:

- Express 4.16
- express-session 1.15.6
- cookie-parser 1.4.3.

**EDIT:**

My website is using SSL, so my `cookie` should have `secure:true`.

**UPDATE:**

I tried moving `res.sendStatus(200)` so that the method now looks like this:

```
conn.query("CALL getUserByGoogleId(?)", [userid])
    .then(rows => {
        if (rows[0]) {
            req.session.test = "Hello, world!";
            console.log("req.session.test = " + req.session.test);
            req.session.user = {
                firstName: rows[0].firstName,
                lastName: rows[0].lastName,
                avatar: rows[0].imageUrl,
            };
        } else {
            conn.query("CALL createUser(?,?,?,?,?)) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
                , [userid, req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName, req.body.imageUrl, req.body.email])
            .then(rows => {
                req.session.user = {
                    firstName: rows[0].firstName,
                    lastName: rows[0].lastName,
                    avatar: rows[0].imageUrl,
                };
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("error: " + err);
                res.send(err);
            });
        }
        res.sendStatus(200);
        conn.end();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send(err);
    });
});
```

and got the same result.

Comment: I cant test it right now but your problem (or one at least of them) is most certainly  `res.sendStatus(200)`, because that is equal to `res.status(200).send('ok')` and ends the response. So you end the response before you do changes to the session and you say `saveUninitialized: false` so at the time you send the response the session is `uninitialized`.

Comment: The whole `verify` function is a bit messy. You have a disconnected Promise chain for which you don't catch potential errors. Your application might become unresponsive over time, as you won't close the request for certain error cases. `CALL createUser(?,?,?,?,?)) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)` uses a connection that is already returned to the pool (or is closed). And I would guess there are more problems in the code.

Comment: I will try moving `res.sendStatus(200)` as soon as I can. I'm used to using session variables in ASP.NET, where they're not attached to the request.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `cookie: { secure: true }` to false, because according to the Doc:

> **Note** be careful when setting this to true, as compliant clients will not send the cookie back to the server in the future if the browser does not have an HTTPS connection.
>
> Please note that secure: true is a recommended option. However, it requires an https-enabled website, i.e., HTTPS is necessary for secure cookies. If secure is set, and you access your site over HTTP, the cookie will not be set.

Code:

```
app.use(
    session({
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        secret: 'debug',
        cookie: { secure: false }
    })
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention in the original post that I'm using SSL, though. I can't remember if I've tried changing it to `false` just to see, so I will do that later today.